# Overall probability of multiple events occuring

Tags: probability

Say you had 100 cards, and within the 100 was 1 marked card.

You then separated the stack of 100 into a stack of 10, and a stack of 90.

You then separated the stack of 90 into a stack of 13, and a stack of 77.

You then drew one card from the stack of 77.

What is the overall chance, accounting for all of the events, to draw the marked card?

Comment: It's $0$, I don't have any.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

What's the chance that it makes it into the stack of $90$?

What's the chance that it makes it into the stack of $77$, given that it made it into the stack of $90$?

What's the chance that you draw it from the stack of $77$, given that it made it in there?

Multiply them all together.